# Code jumps from Then to End If whithout considering the command in-between

Tags: vba, excel

Since hours now I'm struggling with the same problem now...

I try to copy certain rows upon a condition in column A to an other Workbook. I don't get an error message, the code runs through, but nothing happens. Somehow it seems not to "see" the lines between Then and End If. If I run the code manually, the line directly jumps to  End if and further repeats the loop.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong? - Thanks for any help!

This part of my code lookes like:

```
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer

LastRow = Workbooks("Workb1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

If Cells(i, 2).Value = "848" Then
Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 14)).Select

Selection.Copy
Workbooks("destination.xlsx").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A63976").Paste

End If
Next i
```

After your first comments, the edited code now is:

```
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer
Dim ws4 As Worksheet

Set ws4 = Workbooks("Workb1").Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = ws4.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With ws4
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = 848 Then
            Range(.Cells(i, 1)).Select

            Selection.Copy
            Workbooks("destination.xlsx").Activate
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
            Range("A63976").Paste

        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Ok, What I actually want to do:

Always copy from source to target sheet

First only for rows, which have a 848 in column A and paste them to target. So for all those rows, which have an 848 in column A:
Copy value in the column X in “source”  --> Column Y in “target”

- A --> A N-->B O-->C AM -->D AH -->G P-->I E-->J F-->K

Now, only consider those cells with a 618 in column A and copy/paste, again to the firs empty cell in this column (so after the rows with 848, now the target-sheet gets completed with the 618 cells.

1. A --> A N-->B O-->C AM -->D T -->G P-->I E-->J F-->K

Column E and F in the target: there are formula, which have to be elongated to the end of the column

I did change that much until now, that it's not even a working code anymore...

```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


   Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer, LastRow2 As  Integer
   Dim ws4 As Worksheet

   Set ws4 = Workbooks("macro_source").Sheets("Sheet1")
   LastRow = ws4.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   With ws4
       For i = 2 To LastRow
           If .Cells(i, 1).Value = 848 Then
           Workbooks("macro_source").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
               .Cells(i, 1).Copy

       Set erow =    Workbooks("destination.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,    1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
      ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste


       End If
   Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Maybe I have to add, that both files are pre-edited by the prior code, which I did not show here. And I still did not find out whether it's possible to upload the data as excel files...

Many thanks for your help again, I really stuck...

Comment: If it skips lines inside If statement, it means that condition was not met. Please check values in column B, if your condition is met.

Comment: Is the value actually `848` or is it just _formatted_ to look like that?

Comment: Have you added a Watch to check what value is stored in `Cells(i, 2).Value`?

Comment: It's probably due to you're passing an integer value from the cell and comparing it to a string in your macro. Try removing the quotations around the `848` and try running again

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. So 1. I want to run the loop in column A, so I changed that. 2. I tried with and without quotations, that didn't help. I'm not sure about whether 848 is a value or not (even though I think so, the fields in column A are either 848,618 or 724...) As well I changed my code according to your suggestions Tom but that didn't help neither. 
 
I added my edited code again to the question. Thanks for your support!!

Comment: Your revised code is wrong - it should be just `.Cells(i, 1).Copy destination:=            Workbooks("destination.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A63976")` but you'll keep overwriting the same cell that way.

Comment: Yes Rory you are right! How do can I prevent it from overwriting the same cell but filling the row A with the value, starting at the cell     A63976 ?

Comment: Updated code for multiple value searching now included

Comment: @Flephal Thanks, I just did so! In case you want to give it an other try: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33310504/5479421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copying between books seems to go wrong fairly often even when what you have coded seems to logically be correct.

I have found in the past it's better to reference the sheet then use the reference and to use the with statement as it seems to handle range selections better

Some code below should work for you... (I have altered the paste to start at A1 and increment each time as the original code would overwrite each time it found a value - you should be able to edit to paste where you want)

```
Sub CopyToNewBook()
    On Error Resume Next
        Dim wbSrc As Workbook: Set wbSrc = Workbooks("Workb1.xlsx")
        Dim wbDest As Workbook: Set wbDest = Workbooks("destination.xlsx")

        If wbSrc Is Nothing Or wbDest Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Please open both workbooks required"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet: Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long: j = 63976

    With wsSrc
        LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "848" Then
                .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 14)).Copy
                wsDest.Range("A" & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

---

***UPDATE***

For searching against multiple values

```
Sub CopyToNewBook()
    On Error Resume Next
        Dim wbSrc As Workbook: Set wbSrc = Workbooks("Workb1.xlsx")
        Dim wbDest As Workbook: Set wbDest = Workbooks("destination.xlsx")

        If wbSrc Is Nothing Or wbDest Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Please open both workbooks required"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim SearchValues() As String: SearchValues = Split("848,618", ",")

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet: Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, z As Long: z = 63976

    With wsSrc
        LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        For j = 0 To UBound(SearchValues)
            For i = 2 To LastRow
                If .Cells(i, 1).Value = SearchValues(j) Then
                    .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 14)).Copy
                    wsDest.Range("A" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    z = z + 1
                End If
            Next i
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: oh wonderful, the code just runs through! Thanks a lot, you made my night much more pleasant!! Did you see the updated question? If you know any more how to solve- I would be so grateful !

Comment: Oh no, there is an error! for my data, j has to be 63976. But if j=63976, the runtime error "overflow is appearing.  how can I avoid it?

Comment: Use Long instead of Integer; integers can be -32,768 to 32,767 whereas a Long can hold a value up to 2 billion or so; code updated...

Comment: Also; if you're going to update the question like this; it's better to award an answer and ask a new question referencing the old question.

Answer (score 0):

To add to my comment

you're also counting the number of rows in column `A` and running the loop on column `B`. I'd also set your cells as it could be looking at the wrong sheet

```
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer
Dim ws as worksheet

set ws = Workbooks("Workb1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).Row

with ws
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If .Cells(i, 2).Value = 848 Then
            Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 14)).Select

            Selection.Copy
            Workbooks("destination.xlsx").Activate
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
            Range("A63976").Paste

        End If
    Next i
end with
```

---

***Update:***

you could simplify a lot of this

```
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer
Dim ws as worksheet

set ws = Workbooks("Workb1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).Row

with ws
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Trim(Val(.Cells(i, 1))) = 848 Then
            Range(.Cells(i, 2)).Copy _
                destination:=Workbooks("destination.xlsx") _
                .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A63976").Paste
        End If
    Next i
end with
```

This code will work fine. Check your cell that has `848` in it manually and make sure it is an integer.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. So 1. I want to run the loop in column A, so I changed that. 2. I tried with and without quotations, that didn't help. I'm not sure about whether 848 is a value or not (even though I think so, the fields in column A are either 848,618 or 724...)  As well I changed my code according to your suggestions Tom but that didn't help neither.

Comment: I added my edited code again to the question. Thanks for your support!!

Comment: can you step through the code and look at what `LastRow` is evaluating to?

Comment: so it comes back with 400 or whatever the last non blank cell is?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand what you mean. If I run the LastRow line, I see that the whole column A, until the last non blank cell (line 12375), gets "framed"

Comment: I was using 400 just as an example. How does it get "framed" if it isn't going into the if conditional?

Comment: Actually I just saw that this "frame is already before running the line LastRow, so has nothing to do with LastRow. Sorry for confusing. I'm really a beginner with VBA. How do I see to what LastRow evaluates? Did you see the discussion from below, that it worked with 618 (an other value from column A) instead of 848?

Comment: Just seen it. If you step through your code using 'F8' (it will go line by line) and however over LastRow with your mouse you'll be able to see what value it's given. Check that's correct. Then also do a find in the sheet and find where 848 is and make sure it has no spaces or other characters around it as well and that it is a number

Comment: Ahh nice, good to know, thx! LastRow=12372. Yes I looked for values 848 in the Sheet and it did find the in column A, no space or anything else there...

Comment: It found it in column A? Your if conditional checks column B change 'Cells(i, 2)' to 'Cells(i, 1)' in your if statement and give that a go

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I already adjusted that! now it's      If .Cells(i, 1).Value = 848 Then

Comment: @Fben Can you try my updated code and post what it returns with

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer
Dim ws4 As Worksheet

Set ws4 = Workbooks("Workb1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = ws4.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With ws4.Columns(1)
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If .Cells(i).Value = 848 Then
            Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 14)).Select

            Selection.Copy

           Workbooks("destination.xlsx").Activate
           Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
           Range("A63976").Select
           Selection.PasteSpecial

        End If
    Next i
End With
```

EDIT:

Ok, I'm sure this is frowned upon, but this is how I would have solved the issue. It's nothing close to pro-code, but it gets the work done.

```
Range("A1").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
If ActiveCell.Value = 848 Then
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Address(False, False)).Select
Selection.Copy
 Workbooks("destination.xlsx").Activate
           Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
           Range("A63976").Select
           Selection.PasteSpecial
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

If this code does not work, there's something else that's fishy. The code needs to be executed in the worksheet containing the list, which should be placed in column A and contain no blanks.

You can always change which sheet is selected by adding code.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you change my "Book1" to your workbook? I created a simple list with numbers in column A, where one of them was 848, and it works for me. Try setting breakpoints and see if you can fish out the root of the problem.

Comment: Yes It didn't work. But:Now  I changed 848 to 618, just to see whether that would work and surprisingly it did!!! How can it be? So my datasheet is 12372 rows long and the first time 848 appears is in line 742. Could that be an issue? Now it's just jumping from Then to End if again...

Comment: Uhm.. I'm stumped.. Have you tried changing the format for the entire column to text, and then back to general? Try selecting column A, go to "Find/replace", press advanced, check the "Match entire cell contents" box and search for 848 and see if you can find it that way. No blank spaces or other characters in the cells? I'm thinking it's not a code issue. Could you perhaps share you excel file? If you remove any sensitive information first?

Comment: I did as you said- No luck! Ok, I'll make you a mini version of my files!

Comment: how do I share a file with you?

Comment: This wouldn't work. Your `Do` loop is going to test the first cell in the first workbook then as soon as it moves to the new workbook it will look at the cells in there due to the `Active` conditions you're using

Comment: As I said, proper workbook references should be added. It tests each cell in column A, up to the cell containing the desired value. The if-statement needs to be completed with proper "closing the loop"-code if additional values should be checked. I initially provide code that works in the sense that it will fetch the 848-value and do something with it. The offset part at the bottom steps down once for each iteration of the loop.